# Remapping tab key to autocomplete in commandline mode in Vim

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, autocompletion, normal-mode

I am using Vim 7.4 and I wish to map the tab key so I can use new combinations to autocomplete arguments in command mode from the current directory

Contents of current directory:

```
Funwithstrings.cs Funwithstrings.exe Funwithstrings.cs~
```

Using vim in this directory :
I am using following mapping in vim

```
:map! as <tab>
```

Now upon trying this in command mode in the manner

```
:e Fuas.
```

I get

```
:e Fu^I
```

I.e., `^I` two characters instead of special character `<tab>`
instead of one of the filenames-- expected results with tab key.
In a different computer I get `:e Fu<Tab>` - 5 characters.

What am I doing wrong? I am using screen 256 terminal.

Comment: from what I understand that should work out of the box, if the current directory is correct and you are not using vi mode.

Comment: @christian no it doesn't. Using. Mapped key inserts ^I character  literally.  in its place instead of autocompleteing file name - - - intended effect of tab. Same for <esc>

Comment: ah, you have been talking about mapped keys. Then that is expected. See the `'wildcharm'` option for that. Ah, it is already mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default with nocompatible, vim sets `wildchar` to `<tab>` which enables you to tab complete "out of the box."  However, this does not extend to `<tab>`s produced by mappings.

For example, if we `cnoremap as <tab>`, pressing `as`, vim will type literal tabs, which in this case render as `^I`.

The solution is to use `wildcharm`, which is "recognized when used inside a macro" (see `:help wildcharm`):

`set wildcharm=<tab>`.

An alternative to making a mapping to `<tab>` is to just set `wildchar` or `wildcharm` to the key you want.  This works only for single characters.

Comment: Using 'set wildcharm=as'  returns error E521: Number required after =: wildcharm=as. Whereas with 'cnoremap as <tab>'    and 'set wildcharm=<tab>'  are able    to set 'as'  as command line

Comment: i am stikl unable to remap <esc> and other special keys similarly

Comment: I clarified that only single characters are permitted in `wildchar`/`wildcharm`.  I am not sure what you mean about `<esc>`.. As far as I know `wildcharm=<esc>` would work.  But I don't recommend mapping `<esc>` here.

Answer (score 1):

As Mass mentioned above, `wildchar` can contain only one character. It’s restricted by vim design. But it’s actually restricted to use a non-ascii symbol for `wildchar` either. In most cases, it doesn’t matter because people usually use vim for programming only (that means using English letters only) and don’t change their keyboard layouts for smart tricks. But I do!

So, the `wildchar` option can be left as is, i.e. `<Tab>`. Then, to avoid complex constructions in `<C-r>=` create a little function that emulates the keystrokes. At last, map the key sequence you want to use in Command mode to that function.

For example, assume we want to use the `as` sequence for the autocompletion. In such a case, somewhere in `.vimrc`:

```
function! s:wildchar()
    call feedkeys("\<Tab>", 'nt')
    return ''
endfunction

cnoremap <silent> as <C-r>=<SID>wildchar()<CR>
```

Voila!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for sharing!